# Is my example 'introducing state' or otherwise contravening REST / OData standards?

Tags: rest

I'm in the process of implementing a HTTP interface on an embedded device to allow remote control of the device through REST requests. The REST API has been specified by a partner company responsible for creating the remote control software. On my side, everything is written in C on a tight memory constraint, meaning that the REST interface needs to couple easily and closely to how the device operates.

My problem is that the way that the embedded device fundamentally works doesn't quite fit the REST interface they've specified. I've responded with a proposal that would work from my point of view, but their developer has simply replied that it "introduces state" and "would no longer be REST".

My following example will illustrate what they wanted to do originally.

A `GET` to a given resource path would return one or more JSON objects as follows. Each object has a truly unique index, plus a group number it belongs to, plus a state.

```
[
    {
        "index" : "123",
        "group" : "2",
        "someState" : "false"
    },

    {
        "index" : "124",
        "group" : "2",
        "someState" : "false"
    },

    {
        "index" : "125",
        "group" : "3",
        "someState" : "false"
    },

]
```

A `PUT` to that resource path and that object's index, e.g. `some\resource-123` changes the state of that object, such that `someState` would now be `true`.

A  `DELETE` to that resource and index would 'delete' the object entirely.

Now, the issue I have is that, because of how the device *works*, you can `DELETE` objects individually, but you can only `PUT` -- i.e. flip the `someState` -- of all objects at once in a given *group*. That's determined by how the embedded device behaves - and it is fundamental behaviour that cannot be changed.

My proposal is that a `PUT` could not be made to a resource and index; it would have to be made to the resource and *group*. For example, a `PUT` to `some\resource-2` would set the `someState` of the first two objects in the above array. This would then work fine from the point of view of the remote control's UI and we could all be happy. But the developer cries *No! It isn't REST!!!!1one* and rejects my idea.

How have I "introduced state" by proposing this?

If what I have proposed is bad and kittens will indeed die because of it, is there a better way that I could present the objects as a REST resource and allow their states to be changed given the above constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like all objects in a group must have the same state? If so, I would suggest you ask them to expose the groups as an endpoint, with someState as a group property. That should alleviate their concern about introducing state, and let you set state on a group level. Individual objects could still expose state as a read-only property.

```
GET /groups/3
{
   "id": 3,
   "someState": true
}
PUT /groups/3  <!-- sets the state of all objects in the group -->
{
   "id": 3,
   "someState": false
}
GET /objects/5
{
        "index" : "123",
        "group" : "2",
        "someState" : "false"
}
```

Comment: +1. Thanks Eric. Greatly appreciated. That's a really good idea.

Comment: @Trevor No worries. I hope the external dev goes for it.  :-)

Comment: Just out of interest, can anyone offer an opinion on my original proposed scheme? Is it right to say that it would "no longer make it REST" and would "introduce state"?